# JSON object, strange situation with drawing chart, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

When I send data (values and dates) from function (hard coded), everything is ok, json file is populated, and I see the chart, but when I send data from database, there is no chart but I see that json file is also populeted.

Here is code:

```
public class YearlyStat
{
    public string year { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Statistics(int? id)
{
    //var result = db.pricepoints.Where(r => r.commodityID.Equals(id));
    var items = from item in db.pricepoints
                where (item.commodityID == id)
                select item;

    var stats = new List<YearlyStat>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        stats.Add(new YearlyStat
        {
            year = item.date_of_price.ToShortDateString(),
            value = item.value
        });

    }
    //but this works
    //string s = "2.2.2002";
    //double v = 20.20;
    //stats.Add(new YearlyStat { year = s, value = v });
    //or
    //stats.Add(new YearlyStat { year = "2.2.2002", value = 20.20 });

    return Json(stats, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Types are string and double in both cases.

Comment: Have you debugged your code and checked that the list is filled?

Comment: Yes, when i call action manualy like Statistics/1, i see JSON file in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Check your javascript file. Probably is missing the parameter id. If you are using ajax take a look at the parameters ;)

Comment: I fixed it half hour ago, and that was the problem :D